# Faster way to lose weight for med test

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, diet

I had to lose 6kg for my medical test, i already lost 2kgs but I'm stuck now and not loosing weight anymore.someone please tell me a faster and effective way to do this, i just have to lose as much weight as possible temporarily for the test, so how can i do that? 
Also i would like to add that i have 25bmi and my goal is 23bmi and my hieght is 5feet 2 inches

Comment: Faster and more effective than what? You haven't said anything about what you've done. You can't give vague questions and expect solid, pinpoint answers.

Comment: If the goal is not long-term weight loss then go keto to lose glycogen and water stored in the muscle. Go to a sauna to sweat excess water. Drink a lot.

Comment: @IdriK agree but I’m going to speculate that OP is on a short term crash “diet” and that 2kg lost so far is already surely water weight

Comment: BTW to help reduce water weight, avoid sodium and keep carbs low for a couple days before the “weigh in”

Answer (score 1):

You can adopt a juicing diet or fast with exercise.

1lb of body fat has 3500 calories (~8000cal/kg), so losing calories and not replacing them would be the quickest option.

I recommend erring on the side of caution, as I often hear people say to see a doctor before doing this (perhaps diabetes is a concern here), although I'm skeptical of the need to do that, as we adapted to have days without food.

If your body goes into ketosis after some time, you will have increased vision and other senses, because your body is preparing you to find more food.

If you take this route with exersise, you may want to have a protein supplement after workouts to avoid muscle loss.

Note - too much sugar or carbohydrates will kick you out of ketosis as well as very large amounts of protein. Try to keep sugar and carbs under 20g/day

Answer (score -1):

You have to avoid eating all junk and processed foods. Consume food which have less calorie and exercise daily, this would help you decrease your weight.